# fetch next 20 rows slower than fetch next 50 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, fetch

I am using ms sql server. I have a sql looks like this:

```
select ... from 
    (select ... from ... left join .... where ... order by ... offset 0 rows fetch next 50 rows only) a
    left join ...
    left join ...
```

when I change 50 to 20 or 10, the execution is slow, when I use 50, 100 the execution is not so slow, What may result this?

I compare the sqlplan, the two diagram has no difference, except the arguments in each node（step?）.

Also, I change another database, the problem does not happen.

Comment: If you can share execution plans (fast and slow) here, then community can help better -https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: There has  been far to much redacted from your sample query for us to even begin to answer that. Could you provide the entire query? Execution plans may also help. [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer likely has to do with the underlying sorting algorithm being used in the `ORDER BY` clause.  Before fetching the first 10, 20, etc. rows, the records first need to be sorted.  For the purpose of illustration, let's assume that there is no index on the column appearing in `ORDER BY`, and the database is using a divide and conquer sorting algorithm such as mergesort.  For the extreme case of fetching only a single row, the entire sorting algorithm would need to be run.  This is so because we don't know what the single record is until the entire set of records has been sorted.  However, in the case of say fetching 50 records, the entire data set does not need to be sorted.  Rather, once we have reached blocks of 50 records, we can stop that sort, and then only those remaining 50 records might need to be sorted further.

In practice, if the column(s) in your `ORDER BY` clause be indexed, then the above description might change.  In that case, we might only need to traverse a B tree once to find the matching records.  If so, then the performance might not be so different for fetching a small versus large number of records.

Comment: I am using order by clustered index

Answer (score 0):

The difference in execution time can come from a query optimizer. It just can choose different query plans, for instances switches to nested loop join in case of 10 rows, but uses merge in case of 100.

Just compare query execution plans for various variants and see what was changed.

In case if was about types of joins used, you can see if update of statistics of underlying tables helps to get stable performance